# Switch batteries in Thinkpad before performing a deep discharge

Tags: thinkpad, battery

I'm currently looking for a possibility to stop my T480 from deep discharging my external battery, before switching to the internal battery. It should switch to the internal battery at a percentage of about below 7%.

Optionally this should be combined with an automatic hibernate as soon as the internal battery reaches a certain threshold.

So my questions are:

- Is there an existing solution to automatically switch batteries before deep discharging them, which also automatically hibernates if a certain threshold is reached.
- If there is not, is there a way to manually switch between batteries?

It is possible to write a custom script which checks every few seconds whether the batteries reached the thresholds to switch batteries/hibernate.
But for this to work, I would still need a command to manually switch batteries.

Comment: This is probably not a Unix issue. The handover from battery to electrical outlet is usually governed by firmware/internal switches.

Comment: ^^^ that's not an exact duplicate, because they want to discharge the external battery first, but the tools used to achieve that also look appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Information:

"What I found out is that T470 is using a new algorithm which checks the wear level of each battery and first discharges the battery which is worn the least.  This makes sure that the two batteries wear out evenly and maximizes the lifespan of both batteries.  This behavior is different than T460 and earlier systems which always discharge the removable battery first." says, someotherguy on Lenovo Community.

I also fact-checked this myself as I have a Lenovo T550. The info is valid.

So it is likely that they are still implementing this in your T480 and my T550.

- There is no known way to switch batteries at the user's behest. Other than removing the external one and praying the internal one has enough juice to allow the insertion of the next.
- You can set the critical battery option though. Doing this is different depending on distro.

Found the Information: [Lenovo Community](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/T470-power-bridge-wired-battery-discharging-order-always/m-p/3719535#M117180)